# Android Studio 1.3 gradle plugin returns error when defining jni and jniLibs in Source sets

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Could not find property jni and source set 'main'

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 21
        buildToolsVersion = "22.0.1"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.example.native_activity"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 9
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 9
        }

        sourceSets.main {
            jni.srcDirs = [] // This prevents the auto generation of Android.mk
            jniLibs.srcDir = 'src/main/libs'
            // This is not necessary unless you have precompiled libraries in your project.
        }
    }
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.model.internal.core.ModelRuleExecutionException: Exception thrown while executing model rule: model.android
    at org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry.fireMutation(DefaultModelRegistry.java:485)
    at org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry.access$1500(DefaultModelRegistry.java:45)
    at org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry$RunModelAction.apply(DefaultModelRegistry.java:1464)
    at org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry.transitionTo(DefaultModelRegistry.java:341)
    at org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry.transition(DefaultModelRegistry.java:419)
    at org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry.atStateOrMaybeLater(DefaultModelRegistry.java:183)
    at org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry.atStateOrLater(DefaultModelRegistry.java:175)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolver.selfClose(TaskNameResolver.java:101)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolver.selfClosedTasksNode(TaskNameResolver.java:114)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.MissingMethodException: Could not find method main() for arguments [build_f1cmjkxjjzysskbrs6852ixyj$_run_closure1_closure2_closure7@8c09fa7] on SourceSet container.
```

I googled like mad for the last 2 hours...

Comment: 2 hours lol :) I lost 3 days integrating NDK and C libraries with gradle

Comment: have you solved this?

Comment: This crap is supposed to make people save time... :X

Answer (score 9):

As Awanish said - read the [Experimental Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) step by step **VERY** carefully. For even more clearance check the build.gradle files in the [ndk-samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk) provided by google.

`sourceSets.main { }` has different syntax and should be outside the `android { }` block. In your case it should look something like this:

```
model {

    android {
        //...
    }

    android.sources {
        main {
            jniLibs {
                source {
                    srcDirs 'libs'
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The experimental plugin guide was really helpful to resolve my errors.

Comment: How do you then **exclude** specific files?

Answer (score 8):

In my case it was an exact opposite to tochkov answer:

This syntax  - with the jniLibs **outside** android block - gave me an error:

```
android {

   compileSdkVersion 21
   buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.mycompany.myproject"
       minSdkVersion 17
       targetSdkVersion 21
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
          minifyEnabled false
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
    }
}
```

and this syntax - **inside** android block - fixed it:

```
android {

compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mycompany.myproject"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
    }
}
}
```

Comment: **srcDirs** block has to be enclosed inside of **source { }** block!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to use the grade experimental plugin!

Make sure you have grade-2.5 in your `gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.5-all.zip
```

and this in your project's `build.gradle` dependencies tag

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.1.0'
```

Instead of guessing a lot of things, let me redirect you to the user guide, where the documentation explains migration from the standard to experimental plugin in detail. [Take a look here!](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental)

Try these fixes. Post more details if these don't work for you, I will try to help. :)

Comment: Thanks. I did take a look. It seems that I doing the right thing while still getting these errors. I'll spend more time again tomorrow and will update you with my progress (or lack of it).

Answer (score 0):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.jeremy.test"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 15
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
            }
        }
        ndk {
            moduleName "hello-android-jni"
        }
    }

    android.sources.main {
        java.source.srcDirs = ["src/main/java", "/Users/jeremy/Repositories/hello/src/android/java"]
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

The above is copied from my experimental ndk project, this works for me.
See the `android.sources.main` section.